# Prove an integral inequality

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

It is true that 
$$
\int \int\int f(y) f(z) g(x-y)g(x-z)g(x) dx dy dz \leq || f||_2^2 ||g||_2^2
$$

Comment: Have you tried the Fourier transform?